# Modifying the Turtlebot Follower

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I am currently trying to figure out how to modify the built in follower demo. I modified the cpp file but can not figure out how to build the workspace. I have looked around for an answer but have not yet found one.

When I run catkin_make it returns

"The specified source space "/home/bsuwirjo/turtlebotCode/turtlebot_apps-indigo/src" does not exist".

When I try rosmake it returns

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'turtlebot_apps-indigo' is not a package name or stack name.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/bsuwirjo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160204-175201
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

Is it something I'm doing wrong regarding the commands?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226227/modifying-the-turtlebot-follower/) by [bsuwirjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25853/bsuwirjo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you don't have "src" folder.

All packages are situated here:

```
/home/bsuwirjo/turtlebotCode/turtlebot_apps-indigo/src/turtlebot_apps/
```

For instance, path to the turtlebot_follower:

```
/home/bsuwirjo/turtlebotCode/turtlebot_apps-indigo/src/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_follower
```

You run "catkin_make" here:

```
/home/bsuwirjo/turtlebotCode/turtlebot_apps-indigo/
```

---

Originally posted by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) with karma: 77 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsuwirjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25853/bsuwirjo/) on 2016-02-14**:
I downloaded the turtlebot apps folder right off of github and it didn't come with the file structure you mentioned above. Would I have to create them manually? or create a new workspace and copy the turtlebot apps folder into the src directory.

**Comment by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on 2016-02-15**:
Yes, you should create a workspace and copy turtlebot_apps folder into the src directory. (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).

**Comment by [bsuwirjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25853/bsuwirjo/) on 2016-03-03**:
I am now able to build it successfully,however my changes are not being processes. I modified follower.cpp in the src directory and when I catkin_make it is able to detect the changes. However when I run the follower after sourcing, it doesn't change anything. Do you know what the proble is?